# Dlib и pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я использую python3.6.0 и библиотеку dlib. Пытаюсь получить .app файл с помощью PyInstaller. Сама "компиляция" проходит на отлично, однако при попытке запуска получившегося приложения вылезает вот это

```
File "/Users/ivanlebedev/Desktop/Searcher/devEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ivanlebedev/Desktop/Searcher/dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/dlib.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/ivanlebedev/Desktop/Searcher/dist/main.app/Contents/MacOS/dlib.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: dlib.so requires version 51.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 38.0.0
[45539] Failed to execute script main
```

Уже весь интернет перерыл, не знаю что можно сделать?
Спасибо